# Android Apps Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x6f740072 (code=1) with Google Map V2

Tags: android

all.
I am developing an Android app that makes use of the Google Map V2 MapView (The one from the com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView). However, it always return the Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) error and crashed my app.
Here is how it works:
The app contains two activities only. One is the starting activity (CompanyLogo), and all it does is to display a logo and contains a button to allow the user to display the other activity that contains the mapview (GoogleMapView). This activity also contains a button that allows the user to go back to the CompanyLogo activity
Everytime when first I launch the application and click the button, both the CompanyLogo and the GoogleMapView work perfectly. However, if I click on the button in the GoogleMapView in order to go back to the CompanyLogo, the above infamous error will appear and crash the app.
The following are the code for the activities:

CompanyLogo.java

```
package com.example.bumarketingapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;


public class CompanyLogo extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.companylogo);
        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener( 
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(CompanyLogo.this, GoogleMapView.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        );

    }
}
```

companylogo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/companyLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/companylogo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/logo_button"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

GoogleMapView.java

```
package com.example.bumarketingapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.content.Intent;  
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;

public class GoogleMapView extends Activity
{
    MapView mv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.googlemapview);
        mv = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.newmapview);
        mv.onCreate(savedInstance);

        ImageButton currentButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.google_map_info);
        currentButton.setOnClickListener
        (
            new View.OnClickListener()  
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(GoogleMapView.this, CompanyLogo.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        );

    }

    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mv.onResume();
    }
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        mv.onPause();
    }   
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        mv.onDestroy();
    }   
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstance);
        mv.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstance);
    }
    public void onLowMemory()
    {
        super.onLowMemory();
        //Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Low Memory Warning!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mv.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

googlemapview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
   <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapViewxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/newmapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        />
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/google_map_products"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/products"
        />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/google_map_stores"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/stores"
        />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/google_map_info"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/info"
        />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/google_map_discounts"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/discounts"
        />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/google_map_direction"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/routes"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Complete LogCat

```
05-31 03:38:11.830: I/ActivityManager(1259): Displayed com.example.bumarketingapp/.GoogleMapView: +811ms
05-31 03:38:11.860: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 10% free 4241K/4700K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
05-31 03:38:11.960: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 152K, 10% free 4242K/4700K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
05-31 03:38:12.240: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 388K, 11% free 4282K/4808K, paused 18ms, total 21ms
05-31 03:38:12.290: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 23K, 8% free 4470K/4808K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
05-31 03:38:12.520: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 405K, 10% free 4626K/5088K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
05-31 03:38:12.600: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 248K, 10% free 4738K/5240K, paused 20ms, total 21ms
05-31 03:38:12.600: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.678MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:12.600: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 5762K/6268K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
05-31 03:38:12.770: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1566K, 25% free 4972K/6612K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
05-31 03:38:12.770: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.907MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:12.790: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 5995K/6612K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
05-31 03:38:12.940: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1632K, 28% free 4893K/6744K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
05-31 03:38:12.940: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.830MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:12.960: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 13% free 5916K/6744K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
05-31 03:38:13.080: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1407K, 27% free 4939K/6744K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
05-31 03:38:13.080: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.875MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:13.100: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 12% free 5961K/6744K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
05-31 03:38:13.180: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1056K, 27% free 4952K/6744K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
05-31 03:38:13.180: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.887MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:13.200: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 5975K/6744K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
05-31 03:38:13.290: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1068K, 27% free 4953K/6744K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
05-31 03:38:13.290: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.888MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:13.310: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 5977K/6744K, paused 14ms, total 15ms
05-31 03:38:13.420: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1068K, 27% free 4953K/6744K, paused 3ms, total 12ms
05-31 03:38:13.420: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.888MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:13.440: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10K, 12% free 5967K/6744K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
05-31 03:38:13.530: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1052K, 27% free 4944K/6744K, paused 2ms, total 7ms
05-31 03:38:13.540: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.879MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:13.550: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 12% free 5961K/6744K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
05-31 03:38:13.660: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1067K, 27% free 4939K/6744K, paused 0ms, total 4ms
05-31 03:38:13.660: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.875MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:13.660: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 5962K/6744K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
05-31 03:38:13.750: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1068K, 27% free 4939K/6744K, paused 6ms, total 11ms
05-31 03:38:13.750: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.875MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:13.750: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13K, 12% free 5949K/6744K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
05-31 03:38:13.860: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1067K, 27% free 4927K/6744K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
05-31 03:38:13.860: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.862MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:13.880: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 5950K/6744K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
05-31 03:38:13.930: D/ConnectivityService(1259): [CheckMp] isMobileOk: too many loops tried - giving up
05-31 03:38:13.930: D/ConnectivityService(1259): [CheckMp] isMobileOk: X loops|timed out result=0
05-31 03:38:13.930: D/ConnectivityService(1259): [CheckMp] isMobileOk: F stop hipri
05-31 03:38:13.930: D/MobileDataStateTracker(1259): default: setEnableFailFastMobileData(enabled=0)
05-31 03:38:13.930: D/ConnectivityService(1259): stopUsingNetworkFeature: teardown net 0: enableHIPRI
05-31 03:38:13.970: D/dalvikvm(1385): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 535K, 16% free 3263K/3852K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
05-31 03:38:13.980: D/MobileDataStateTracker(1259): hipri: Broadcast received: android.intent.action.ANY_DATA_STATE apnType=hipri
05-31 03:38:13.980: D/MobileDataStateTracker(1259): hipri: Received state=DISCONNECTED, old=CONNECTED, reason=dataDisabled
05-31 03:38:13.980: D/MobileDataStateTracker(1259): hipri: setDetailed state, old =CONNECTED and new state=DISCONNECTED
05-31 03:38:13.980: D/ConnectivityService(1259): ConnectivityChange for mobile_hipri: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED
05-31 03:38:14.000: E/logwrapper(1850): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
05-31 03:38:14.010: E/SecondaryTablController(920): ip route del failed: /system/bin/ip route del 10.0.2.2/32 via 0.0.0.0 dev eth0 table 60
05-31 03:38:14.010: E/logwrapper(1851): executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
05-31 03:38:14.010: W/FrameworkListener(920): Handler 'interface' error (No such device)
05-31 03:38:14.030: E/SecondaryTablController(920): ip route del failed: /system/bin/ip route del 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 table 60
05-31 03:38:14.030: W/FrameworkListener(920): Handler 'interface' error (No such device)
05-31 03:38:14.030: D/Nat464Xlat(1259): requiresClat: netType=5, hasIPv4Address=true
05-31 03:38:14.040: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1067K, 27% free 4927K/6744K, paused 3ms, total 4ms
05-31 03:38:14.050: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.862MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:14.070: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 5950K/6744K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
05-31 03:38:14.180: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1067K, 27% free 4927K/6744K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
05-31 03:38:14.180: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.863MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:14.200: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 5950K/6744K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
05-31 03:38:14.290: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1067K, 27% free 4927K/6744K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
05-31 03:38:14.290: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.863MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:14.310: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 5951K/6744K, paused 15ms, total 16ms
05-31 03:38:14.420: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1067K, 27% free 4928K/6744K, paused 13ms, total 14ms
05-31 03:38:14.420: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.864MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:14.440: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 5952K/6744K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
05-31 03:38:14.530: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1066K, 27% free 4929K/6744K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
05-31 03:38:14.530: I/dalvikvm-heap(1740): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.865MB for 1048588-byte allocation
05-31 03:38:14.550: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 12% free 5953K/6744K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
05-31 03:38:14.950: D/dalvikvm(1259): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 842K, 17% free 6361K/7640K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
05-31 03:38:15.270: D/dalvikvm(1740): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2084K, 31% free 4952K/7092K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
05-31 03:38:15.570: D/dalvikvm(1259): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1076K, 19% free 6205K/7640K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
05-31 03:38:15.800: D/dalvikvm(1259): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 881K, 19% free 6205K/7640K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
05-31 03:38:15.950: D/dalvikvm(1259): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 881K, 19% free 6205K/7640K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
05-31 03:38:16.010: I/ActivityManager(1259): Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{b335bf68 u0 com.android.music/.MediaPlaybackService}
05-31 03:38:16.010: V/AlarmClock(1622): AlarmInitReceiver android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
05-31 03:38:16.010: I/ActivityManager(1259): Resuming delayed broadcast
05-31 03:38:16.030: V/AlarmClock(1622): AlarmInitReceiver - Reset timers and clear stopwatch data
05-31 03:38:16.040: I/AlarmClock(1622): Displaying next alarm time: ''
05-31 03:38:16.050: V/AlarmClock(1622): AlarmInitReceiver finished
05-31 03:38:16.050: D/dalvikvm(924): GC_EXPLICIT freed 39K, 4% free 2697K/2792K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 5ms
05-31 03:38:16.050: I/ActivityManager(1259): Start proc com.android.email for broadcast com.android.email/.service.EmailBroadcastReceiver: pid=1856 uid=10024 gids={50024, 3003, 1028, 1015}
05-31 03:38:16.080: D/dalvikvm(924): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 4% free 2697K/2792K, paused 0ms+1ms, total 30ms
05-31 03:38:16.100: D/dalvikvm(924): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 4% free 2697K/2792K, paused 15ms+0ms, total 17ms
05-31 03:38:16.280: I/ActivityManager(1259): Delay finish: com.android.email/.service.EmailBroadcastReceiver
05-31 03:38:16.350: I/Email(1856): Observing account changes for notifications
05-31 03:38:16.350: W/ActivityManager(1259): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.android.email/.service.AttachmentDownloadService } U=0: not found
05-31 03:38:16.360: I/ActivityManager(1259): Delaying start of: ServiceRecord{b348d3c0 u0 com.android.exchange/.service.EmailSyncAdapterService}
05-31 03:38:16.380: D/dalvikvm(1259): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 850K, 19% free 6236K/7640K, paused 8ms, total 9ms
05-31 03:38:16.410: I/ActivityManager(1259): Start proc com.android.exchange for service com.android.exchange/.service.EmailSyncAdapterService: pid=1876 uid=10025 gids={50025, 3003, 1028, 1015}
05-31 03:38:16.430: D/dalvikvm(1876): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
05-31 03:38:16.510: I/LauncherIconVisibilityManager(1343): Boot has been completed
05-31 03:38:16.510: I/LauncherIconVisibilityManager(1343): Activity has already been disabled: ComponentInfo{com.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.setup.SetupActivity}
05-31 03:38:16.510: I/ActivityManager(1259): Resuming delayed broadcast
05-31 03:38:16.520: D/GCM(1469): GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE
05-31 03:38:16.520: I/ActivityManager(1259): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.init.InitializeGmsReceiver
05-31 03:38:16.530: I/ActivityManager(1259): Resuming delayed broadcast
05-31 03:38:16.580: I/SystemUpdateService(1371): acquiring wakelock
05-31 03:38:16.580: I/SystemUpdateService(1371): onCreate
05-31 03:38:16.600: I/SystemUpdateService(1371): cancelUpdate (empty URL)
05-31 03:38:16.620: D/GCM(1469): GcmService start Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService (has extras) } android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
05-31 03:38:16.650: I/SystemUpdateService(1371): cancelUpdate (empty URL)
05-31 03:38:16.660: I/SystemUpdateService(1371): releasing wakelock
05-31 03:38:16.680: I/SystemUpdateService(1371): acquiring wakelock
05-31 03:38:16.680: I/SystemUpdateService(1371): onCreate
05-31 03:38:16.690: I/SystemUpdateService(1371): cancelUpdate (empty URL)
05-31 03:38:16.690: I/SystemUpdateService(1371): cancelUpdate (empty URL)
05-31 03:38:16.700: D/GCM(1469): GcmService start Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService (has extras) } android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
05-31 03:38:16.700: I/SystemUpdateService(1371): releasing wakelock
05-31 03:38:16.700: I/GCM(1469): requestRouteToHost: failed!
05-31 03:38:16.710: I/ActivityManager(1259): Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{b33cede0 u0 com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService}
05-31 03:38:16.730: D/PackageBroadcastService(1371): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.example.bumarketingapp
05-31 03:38:16.730: I/ActivityManager(1259): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.app.receiver.SystemBroadcastReceiver
05-31 03:38:16.780: D/dalvikvm(1371): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 441K, 19% free 3064K/3756K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
05-31 03:38:16.810: I/Icing(1371): Storage manager: low false usage 56.11KB avail 110.85MB capacity 167.55MB
05-31 03:38:16.820: I/ActivityManager(1259): Resuming delayed broadcast
05-31 03:38:16.840: I/ActivityManager(1259): Start proc com.google.android.gms.drive for broadcast com.google.android.gms/.drive.api.DriveSystemBroadcastReceiver: pid=1913 uid=10052 gids={50052, 3003, 1007, 1028, 1015, 3002, 3001, 2001, 3006}
05-31 03:38:16.850: I/MultiDex(1913): load(/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk, forceReload=false)
05-31 03:38:16.870: E/Icing(1371): Could not mmap file for reading: Invalid argument
05-31 03:38:16.910: D/dalvikvm(1913): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 162K, 7% free 3047K/3264K, paused 14ms, total 15ms
05-31 03:38:16.910: D/dalvikvm(1913): GC_CONCURRENT freed 9K, 7% free 3054K/3264K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 3ms
05-31 03:38:16.910: I/MultiDex(1913): Need extracted file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk.classes2.zip
05-31 03:38:16.920: I/MultiDex(1913): No extraction needed for /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/secondary-dexes/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk.classes2.zip of size 1809539
05-31 03:38:16.950: I/ActivityManager(1259): Start proc com.android.keychain for broadcast com.android.keychain/.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver: pid=1928 uid=1000 gids={41000, 1028, 1015, 3002, 3001, 3003}
05-31 03:38:16.980: W/ContextImpl(1928): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1479 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2419 
05-31 03:38:16.980: I/ActivityManager(1259): Delay finish: com.android.keychain/.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver
05-31 03:38:17.000: I/ActivityManager(1259): Resuming delayed broadcast
05-31 03:38:17.030: I/ActivityManager(1259): Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.app.receiver.SystemBroadcastReceiver
05-31 03:38:17.060: D/CaptivePortalTracker(1259): NoActiveNetworkState{ when=-5ms what=1 obj=NetworkInfo: type: mobile_hipri[UMTS], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, reason: dataDisabled, extra: epc.tmobile.com, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
05-31 03:38:17.060: D/CaptivePortalTracker(1259): NoActiveNetworkState not a wifi connectivity change, ignore
05-31 03:38:17.060: D/CaptivePortalTracker(1259): NoActiveNetworkState{ when=-4ms what=1 obj=NetworkInfo: type: mobile[UMTS], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: connected, extra: epc.tmobile.com, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
05-31 03:38:17.060: D/CaptivePortalTracker(1259): NoActiveNetworkState not a wifi connectivity change, ignore
05-31 03:38:17.080: D/PackageBroadcastService(1371): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.example.bumarketingapp
05-31 03:38:17.080: D/Tethering(1259): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
05-31 03:38:17.080: D/Tethering(1259): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
05-31 03:38:17.140: D/ConnectivityService(1259): handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=0, condition=100, published condition=100
05-31 03:38:17.210: I/ActivityManager(1259): START u0 {cmp=com.example.bumarketingapp/.CompanyLogo} from pid 1740
05-31 03:38:17.220: E/SoundPool(1259): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: W/AudioService(1259): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: E/SoundPool(1259): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: W/AudioService(1259): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: E/SoundPool(1259): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: W/AudioService(1259): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: E/SoundPool(1259): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: W/AudioService(1259): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: E/SoundPool(1259): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: W/AudioService(1259): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: E/SoundPool(1259): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: W/AudioService(1259): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: E/SoundPool(1259): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: W/AudioService(1259): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: E/SoundPool(1259): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: W/AudioService(1259): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: E/SoundPool(1259): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: W/AudioService(1259): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: E/SoundPool(1259): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: W/AudioService(1259): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
05-31 03:38:17.220: W/AudioService(1259): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
05-31 03:38:17.230: D/dalvikvm(1371): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 394K, 16% free 3180K/3756K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
05-31 03:38:17.390: I/PeopleContactsSync(1371): CP2 sync disabled
05-31 03:38:17.420: W/EGL_emulation(1740): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-31 03:38:17.430: D/dalvikvm(1259): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 805K, 18% free 6295K/7640K, paused 26ms, total 30ms
05-31 03:38:17.590: I/ActivityManager(1259): Displayed com.example.bumarketingapp/.CompanyLogo: +375ms
05-31 03:38:17.620: D/dalvikvm(1469): GC_EXPLICIT freed 499K, 22% free 3064K/3924K, paused 1ms+12ms, total 17ms
05-31 03:38:17.710: I/Icing(1371): updateResources: need to parse fcu{com.google.android.gms}
05-31 03:38:17.860: D/dalvikvm(1371): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 410K, 13% free 3282K/3756K, paused 95ms, total 95ms
05-31 03:38:17.940: D/dalvikvm(1371): GC_EXPLICIT freed 152K, 15% free 3210K/3756K, paused 13ms+1ms, total 18ms
05-31 03:38:17.980: A/libc(1740): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1841 (Thread-77)
```

I tried to run the app in the debug mode. It seems that the error happen when the time I set the onClick listener for the only button in the CompanyLogo activity in the onCreate method. More correctly, it is the following line of code that caused the problem :

```
    startButton.setOnClickListener( new ...... )
```

I spend days on fixing this problem but still get no solution. 
F.Y.I. 
The MapFragment also cause the same problem too!
I cut part of the LogCat since the whole content excessed the limit

Any help will be much appreciated!!!

Comment: I bet your are using the emulator

Comment: Yes. Does this caused the problem?

Comment: I've got a really similar problem, I think it's an emulator bug. You can try with a real phone, I bet it works good.

Comment: I'm going through the same issue on the x86 4.4.2 emulator with HAXM and Host GPU checked. Don't have a x86 device to test

Comment: Also, the crash consistently happens exactly (as in next-stepping while debugging) when I call mapView#onDestroy